# Apply CSS styles to specific tag using nth-child even exists other tags between them

Tags: html, css

I have simple question for experts in CSS3 about `nth-child` selector (here I'm extemely n00b)

I have the following simple html code:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<span>span3</span>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

a css style:

```
div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    color: red;
}

div, span {
    float: left;
}
```

I created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8aPe/

The results is:

`123span345` where 1,3,4 and 5 is colored as red.

What I'm expect is: `1,3,5` to be red.

Why ? `nth-child` doesn't care about tag child ? or it just refers to an element (doesn't matter what tag have) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, `nth-child` decides based on the element's position among all its siblings. What you want is `nth-of-type` which bases it on the element's position among all its potential css matches.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8aPe/1/

```
div:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference. You should check browser support though, if memory serves `nth-of-type` is not as well supported as `nth-child`

Comment: I'll take care about browser compatibility :)

Comment: Unfortunately yea, only IE9 and above. One day we'll get all the css3 toys.

Comment: Actually, it's got the same support as `nth-child`, so ignore me, I'm getting it confused with Selectivizr's polyfill support for `nth-of-type`

Comment: You can get jquery extended selectors in order to work with selectivizr for IE6-IE8.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `:nth-of-type()` instead of `:nth-child()`